# return values using session in models

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter-2, session-state

I need to make an appointment through the session (id).

My Model:

```
public function get_all($id=NULL){
    if ($id != NULL):
        $id = $this->session->userdata($id);
        $this->db->where('id_user', $id);
        $this->db->like('tipo_user', 'inquilino');
        return $this->db->get('users');
        endif;
}
```

My View:

```
$query = $this->sindico->get_all()->result();
```

**I need to show all residents who belong to the liquidator**

Example of how it would be my query:

```
select * from user where id_user = 1 and tipo_user = "%residents%"
```

When performing this error appears:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in

Comment: You set `$id` to `null` here `public function get_all($id=NULL){` but you don't pass an id through in your view `$this->sindico->get_all()->result();  ` so your if statement inside the function is skipped.. You aren't even getting to the query part.

Comment: Hello . I'm brasieliro . Sorry about my English. Disregard = after like

Comment: can tell me. how to get my model ?

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
public function get_all($id=NULL){
    if ($id == NULL):
        $id = $this->session->userdata($id);
        $this->db->where('id_user', $id);
        $this->db->like('tipo_user', 'inquilino');
        return $this->db->get('users');
    endif;
}
```

### Fixing the issue with $id being null

Since you are not passing an id in your view (for example: 
`$query = $this->sindico->get_all($id)->result();` you are skipping the whole function since you set `$id=NULL` if no reference is passed.

This is the reason to why it says `Call to a member function result() on a non-object in`.

You have 2 options; since you are using `$id=NULL` as the parameter to your query you will need to put an `else` statement for the times you do pass an `$id` so you will need to do:

```
public function get_all($id=NULL){
    if ($id == NULL):
        $id = $this->session->userdata($id);
        $this->db->where('id_user', $id);
        $this->db->like('tipo_user', 'inquilino');
        return $this->db->get('users');

    else:
        $this->db->where('id_user', $id);
        $this->db->like('tipo_user', 'inquilino');
        return $this->db->get('users');

    endif;
}
```

alternativly if you are never going to pass an `$id` as reference then you can remove the whole if statement and do:

```
public function get_all(){
    $id = $this->session->userdata($id);
    $this->db->where('id_user', $id);
    $this->db->like('tipo_user', 'inquilino');
    return $this->db->get('users');
}
```